# RStudio doesn't detect the .gitconfig file on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, bash, rstudio

If I commit using RStudio instead of Git bash, then a message pops up with the following:

*... commit message ...*

*Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate. You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the following command ...*

*... command to edit the globals ...*

RStudio points to this executable in the following folder:

```
C:/Users/kro/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/bin/git.exe
```

Windows points to this:

```
C:\Users\kro\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe
```

If I open a shell through RStudio or if I just open git bash through Windows, then `user.name` and `user.email` looks correct.

My .gitconfig file is located here:

```
C:/users/kro/documents/.gitconfig
```

My session info (everything should be updated):

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.0.143)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Danish_Denmark.1252         
 tz       Europe/Paris                
 date     2017-05-16                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version date       source                                  
 assertthat   0.2.0   2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 base       * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 compiler     3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 datasets   * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 DBI          0.6-1   2017-04-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 devtools     1.13.1  2017-05-13 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 digest       0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 dplyr      * 0.5.0   2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 graphics   * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 grDevices  * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 memoise      1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 methods    * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 R6           2.2.1   2017-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 Rcpp         0.12.10 2017-03-19 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 stats      * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 stringi      1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 stringr      1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 tibble       1.3.0   2017-04-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                          
 tools        3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 utils      * 3.4.0   2017-04-21 local                                   
 withr        1.0.2   2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
```

I've had this problem before with Windows 7, so this is not just an issue with Windows 10.

UPDATE: I inserted the link to git bash that Win 10 use.

UPDATE: I suspect it could be an issue with our network folders as git sometimes think that one of the network folders is the ~. However, I've tried to save a .gitconfig file in the folder and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that RStudio opens git directly from git.exe, rather than from sh.exe -login -i, as the git bash shell does.  The latter reads the global config file from one directory (in my case, evidently the directory pointed to by my HOME environment entry, whereas (in Windows) the git.exe itself reads the global git configuration file in the Windows {HOME} directory -- in my case, c:/users/[my longin name]/.  I copied the .gitconfig file from my HOME directory to my {HOME} directory, and the problem was solved.

Of course, this leaves me with two .gitconfig files that have to be kept in sync, which is suboptimal.  It would be nice if RStudio would permit us to open git *with some command line options* to change the default location of  the global .gitconfig file.  But git doesn't seem to have an option in any case to tell it to look for the global .gitconfig file somewhere else than in its hardwired directory.

Fortunately I don't anticipate that I'll need to edit the global configuration file too often.  So the inconvenience is minor.

Comment: Copying the .gitconfig file to {HOME} does fix my problem, but only when I'm not connected to our network drives.